# Pdf image resized getting blurred only getting partial in pdfbox

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I have a large image and I want to print it inside my PDF document, I am writing the follows:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/mylargeimage.jpg"));
PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(doc, in);
img.setHeight(100);
img.setWidth(100);
contentStream.drawImage(img,50,pageYaxis);
```

I am getting the image printed but the image getting blurred and not getting the full image inside. I needed the image to be resized 100X100. How can I overcome this? Please help me guys?? I had refereed a lot but nothing is clear.

Comment: Did you try to scale the image before passing it to PDJpeg?  Make sure you keep the ratios, else you're image will be blurred.

Comment: It is a VERY bad idea to scale before passing it to PDJPeg because this would lower the quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing it like this?

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/mylargeimage.jpg"));
PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(doc, in);
contentStream.drawXObject(img, 50, pageYaxis, 100, 100);
```

The Javadoc for `drawImage` says that it will draw at the default size of the image. The Javadoc for `drawXObject` says:

> Draw an xobject(form or image) at the x,y coordinates and a certain
>   width and height.

Calling `setWidth` and `setHeight` on the image itself will, I believe, only change what PDFBox believes to be the real size of the image - so it takes only 100x100 pixels of the image as the source.